NextJS / Vercel - Import failing on deployment, but not locally
This one is doing my head in. My local build works fine, but when I push to Vercel the deployment fails and I get this error "Module not found: Can't resolve '@/scripts/fadeInElements'".
This is what I'm using to input the script
import fadeInElements from '@/scripts/fadeInElements'

And this is the script at this stage
export default function fadeInElements() {
  let pElements = document.querySelectorAll('p')
  console.log(pElements)
}


Ah, actually, this fixed it. I think it's because I renamed a file and pushing to git didn't update it
git rm -r --cached .
git add --all .
git commit -a -m "Versioning untracked files"
git push origin master


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
